# Using C pointers to track Fortran module data members

Tags: fortran

We have a legacy Fortran 90 code that operates on a single set of data arrays and would like to extent the code so that we can have several sets of the data. Unfortunately, none of the subroutine takes input arguments and instead, all the data are assess through the module. Following codes are analogous of our Fortran code.

```
MODULE test_mod
    IMPLICIT NONE

    double precision, pointer :: f_x(:)
    integer :: n = 5
END MODULE test_mod

SUBROUTINE alloc_x()
    use test_mod
    IMPLICIT NONE

    allocate(f_x(n))
END SUBROUTINE alloc_x

SUBROUTINE init_x()
    USE test_mod
    IMPLICIT NONE

    f_x = 1.0
END SUBROUTINE init_x

SUBROUTINE dealloc_x()
    use test_mod
    IMPLICIT NONE

    deallocate(f_x)
END SUBROUTINE dealloc_x
```

Since the Fortran code is complicated enough (there are about one hundred arrays and are all in different shapes and sizes), the less the modification of the code the better. We have come up with following solution and are interested in whether this solution would be considered compatible with Fortran 90 standards:

We create two extra Fortran subroutines that stores the location of allocated Fortran arrays and copies the c pointer back to the module.

```
SUBROUTINE store_ptrs(c_x)
    use iso_c_binding
    use test_mod
    IMPLICIT NONE

    TYPE(c_ptr) :: c_x

    c_x = c_loc(f_x)
END SUBROUTINE

SUBROUTINE copy_ptrs2mod(c_x)
    use iso_c_binding
    use test_mod
    IMPLICIT NONE

    TYPE(c_ptr) :: c_x
    CALL c_f_pointer(c_x,f_x,[n])
END SUBROUTINE
```

With these two subroutines, we can have more that one copy of the data (10 copies in the following code) without the need to change the Fortran code --

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void alloc_x_();
void init_x_();
void dealloc_x_();
void store_ptrs_(double **c_x);
void copy_ptrs2mod_(double **c_x);

void output_result(int entry, double* array);

int main()
{
    int i;
    double *x[10];

    /* allocate array */
    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        alloc_x_();
        store_ptrs_(&x[i]);
    }

    /* initialize array */
    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        copy_ptrs2mod_(&x[i]);
        init_x_();
        output_result(i,x[i]);
    }

    /* deallocate the array */
    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        copy_ptrs2mod_(&x[i]);
        dealloc_x_();
    }
}

void output_result(int entry, double* array){
    int j;
    printf("x[%2d] = [", entry);
    for (j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
    {
        if (j == 4)
        {
            printf("%3.1f",array[j]);
            continue;
        }
        printf("%3.1f, ",array[j]);
    }
    printf("]\n");
}
```

Output -

```
x[ 0] = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
x[ 1] = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
x[ 2] = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
x[ 3] = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
x[ 4] = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
x[ 5] = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
x[ 6] = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
x[ 7] = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
x[ 8] = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
x[ 9] = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

While we have yet to see any problems with this, we are a bit concerned that we might be (implicitly) relying on compiler specific implementations of various standards, or that some other incompatibility with more recent standards might prevent this from working. We would greatly appreciate any comments or feedback on this approach to handling what must be a common problem with legacy Fortran 90 codes.

Comment: The module `iso_c_binding` was not standardized until Fortran 2003.

Comment: Fortran 90 is completely obsolete. Forget it, do not require Fortran 90 compliance. Use *at least* Fortran 95 which fixed the biggest problems, but better Fortran 2003 or 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will not say that your code/approach is correct, but I will identify one thing that causes me initial concern.  You can address this simply.

From the fact that you have name mangling to give, on the C side, the prototypes

```
void alloc_x_();
void init_x_();
void dealloc_x_();
void store_ptrs_(double **c_x);
void copy_ptrs2mod_(double **c_x);
```

this suggests that the Fortran procedures are outside any module (you don't have `bind(c,name='alloc_x_')` etc. in the subroutine statements).  Before Fortran 2008 there is a rule about module variables becoming undefined when the module is no longer referenced in an active scope.

In the C execution as you have it, `alloc_x` is entered `test_mod` is referenced.  But as soon as the subroutine completes `test_mod` is no longer referenced in any active scope.  Under Fortran 90 to Fortran 2003 rules the module variable `f_x` becomes undefined at that point.  After that, in `store_ptrs` the reference in `c_loc(f_x)` is non-compliant.

Adding the `save` attribute to the module local variable, or following the Fortran 2008 standard, resolves this issue.

---

Having said that, under Fortran 2003 C interoperability rules, `f_x` is not a valid argument to `c_loc`: a pointer argument must be scalar.

Comment: Do you know any compilers still used today which actually behaved that way.in some old version?

Comment: No. It's one of those "you're probably safe", but the question did essentially ask at a language-lawyer level.  With my edit it's probably moot anyway...